# Pass parameter from onCreate to onClick

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is my kotlin/android activity:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_player_details.*

class PlayerDetails : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_details)

        val intent = getIntent()
        val numOfPlayers = intent.getIntExtra("number_of_players", 1)    
        next_details.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        for (player in 1..numOfPlayers) {
            // body in here

        }
    }

}
```

I want to pass the value of `numOfPlayers` to my `onClick` method so I can use it -  how can I achieve this?

Comment: make `numOfPlayers` global

Comment: Getting this error: https://i.imgur.com/TTLZWuu.png

Comment: this is not how the variables are made global

Comment: @Zorgan No he didn't mean actually use the keyword `global`, just declare the variable:

Comment: Have you tried moving `val numOfPlayers = intent.getIntExtra("number_of_players", 1)` to `onClick`?

Answer (score 2):

Either make numOfPlayer as global variable or create separate function to call when btn is clicked and pass numOfPlayer as parameter

**1. make numOfPlayer as global variable**

```
class PlayerDetails : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {
    var numOfPlayers = 0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_details)

        val intent = getIntent()
        numOfPlayers = intent.getIntExtra("number_of_players", 1)
        next_details.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        for (player in 1..numOfPlayers) {
            // body in here
        }
    }
}
```

**2. create separate function to call when btn is clicked and pass numOfPlayer as parameter**

```
class PlayerDetails : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_details)
        val intent = getIntent()
        val numOfPlayers = intent.getIntExtra("number_of_players", 1)
        bottomNav.setOnClickListener {
            onNextClick(numOfPlayers)
        }
    }

    private fun onNextClick(numOfPlayers: Int) {
        for (player in 1..numOfPlayers) {
            // body in here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your variable with global scope like below

```
var numOfPlayers = 0
```

Make sure to define it above `onCreate()` method.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate` is called when the activity is created, and `onClick` is called when the `next_details` button is clicked, which definitely happens after `onCreate`.

So make `numOfPlayers` a class member and assign the value to it in `onCreate`, and also add the `lateinit` keyword to `numOfPlayers` so you don't need to make it nullable.

The code should look like this:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_player_details.*

class PlayerDetails : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    lateinit var numOfPlayers: Integer
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player_details)

        val intent = getIntent()
        numOfPlayers = intent.getIntExtra("number_of_players", 1)    
        next_details.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        for (player in 1..numOfPlayers) {
            // body in here

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using `lateinit var numOfPlayers: Integer` over `var numOfPlayers: Int = 0` ?

Comment: `lateinit` isn't necessary, it's just there to remind you that this variable shall be initialized before being used. If in case you forget to initialize the variable before using it you will get a special exception, while if you use the latter no exceptions will be thrown if you forget to reassign a value. So it can help you prevent potential uninitialized variable bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Make numOfPlayers global
`var numOfPlayers =0`

In `onCreate()`

```
val intent = getIntent()
numOfPlayers = intent.getIntExtra("number_of_players", 1)
```

In onClick()

```
for (i in 1..numOfPlayers) {
            // body in here

        }
```